# Registration form says username is already in use when it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here are the HTML and JavaScript codes:

```
if (username == '' || password == '' || firstname == '' || secondname == '' || email == '') {
  alert("Please fill all the fields!");
} else if ((password.length) < 8) {
  alert("Password should have at least 8 characters in length!");
} else {
  $.post("register.php", {
      username1: username,
      password1: password,
      firstname1: firstname,
      secondname1: secondname,
      email1: email
    },
    function(data) {
      if (data == 'You have successfully registered!') {
        $("form-horizontal")[0].reset();
      }
      alert(data);
    });
```

[HTML & JS](https://jsfiddle.net/17tt8yk2/1/)

And the php:
[PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1bd15610eaa413ca234cbe04986639ca591c802b)

My problem is that no matter what the fields in the registration contain and/or if the username is in the database or not, I get the same error:

This username is already registered! Please, try again!

Comment: mind posting your mysql?

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire. [Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: @Fred-ii- meaning what? the queries or the actual table?

Comment: maybe your mysql is failing

Comment: You have to read again about how to evaluate a query against the database. You test `if(!$result)` which does not make any sense. `$result` will contain a result handle if the query was valid. It will _not_ contain true or false depending on a row having been found or not. In other world: it will never evaluate to `false`, except if you sql query contains a syntax error (which it does not).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am currently using it for other parts of the website that work fine, so although the server may be slow, it doesn't fail

Comment: I'm no PHP developer but this `$sql1="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; ` looks like you're in for some serious trouble. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Stephen meaning what?

Comment: @arch1ve [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Stephen I am not worried about that right now, because that is not the purpose of the project I am working on (i.e. nobody will try to ruin my database), but thanks for the heads up

Comment: @arch1ve, have you taken into account that the message you get is nowhere in the code snippet you paste? probably the code will be failing in some other code snippet you have not pasted.  How do you want to be helped, if you paste the correct code and hide the failing one?

Comment: @LuisColorado Please check the links in the post before making such comments.

Comment: @arch1ve, the reason of my comments is the same for it to be put on hold. It's not my problem to have to dig in your code, it's your problem to be as explicit and simple as possible for us to be able to help you solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP script you don't check if there are any rows with the query, you only check if the query is not null.

You can fix it by changing the `if` statement to this:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql1);
if(!$result->num_rows)
{
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$firstname', '$secondname', '$email')";
    $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
    if($result2) // Insert query
    {
        echo "You have successfully registered!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error!";
    }
```

I suggest taking a look here to see what I changed:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

A better way to check if a string is empty is by doing this instead of what you have now:

```
if (username == null || password == null || firstname == null || secondname == null || email == null)
```

I also suggest checking in PHP if everything has a value because Javascript can be altered when you inspect the element.

You also need to prepare your statements, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection at the moment and you absolutely don't want that.

More about how to do that can be found here:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Changed that if statement now, and it goes to the else branch of the second if, printing "Error!" Also, I am not concerned about SQL injection right now, because nobody will try to ruin my database (personal project).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is a personal project or not, you should always use the correct security things. If the `if` statement didn't work it is due to an error in your query.

Comment: The first `if` statement works, but after that, when it gets to `if($result2)` and it doesn't evaluate to true, then it just goes to the `else` statement, echoing "Error!"

Comment: Because the query you are checking there is incorrect. Try executing the query in the database and see if it does work there.

Comment: Yes!!! The problem was that the `email` column wasn't even in the table (I simply thought it was, because I am not the one who created the database and it should have been there). Thank you for hinting me to check it!

Comment: No problem, I suggest when developing something enabling errors, you can do this by adding this on the first line of your code: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`